# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object error in test class

Tags: unit-test, customsetting, custom

I am getting null pointer exception while creating a test class for schedule apex

```java
         static testMethod void testMethod2(){        
         test.startTest();    
         Settings__cPS = new ProcessSetting__c(name = 'Corre',Max_Process__c=10);
         insert ps;
         system.debug('Process' + ps.Process__c);
        BatchSchedule obj1 = new BatchSchedule();
         String sch = '0 0 10 * * ?';
         system.schedule('TestCheck', sch, obj1); 
         test.stopTest(); 
      }
```

Sechedue class for which i am trying to write test metho

```
global class CorreSchedule implements Schedulable{

    global static void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        Settings__csetting =  Setting__c.getInstance('Corr);
        Integer oppsize = Integer.valueOf(setting.Process__c);
        final Integer Process = oppsize;
        BatchCorrespondence CNR = new BatchCorrespondence();      
        ID idBatch = Database.executeBatch(CNR,MaxProcess); 
    }
}
```

I am storing limit in custom setting

Comment: is there a typo - line 3 won't compile; please also identify where (line #) in this testmethod the null pointer exception occurs. See [ask] for guidance

Comment: Yes it might be typo there is no compile error

Comment: added sechdule class in question

Comment: error coming in line no 4 of sechule class

Comment: Please properly format the scheduleclass. Use [edit] and fix typo in test class.

Comment: @roshni , i would recommend to add null check in schedular class before using Integer.valueOf to prevent exception incase custom setting is not present.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with Batch and Test class

1. Your class name doesn't matches with the name used in your test class
2. You're not inserting the custom setting record with correct name which is used while retrieving the record.
3. The API name `Max_Process__c` is used while instantiating the custom setting record however in the debug statement its only `process__c`.

Refer below corrected code:

```
global class CorreSchedule implements Schedulable{

    global static void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        Settings__c setting =  Setting__c.getInstance('Corr);
        if (setting != null) {
           Integer oppsize = Integer.valueOf(setting.Max_Process__c);
           final Integer Process = oppsize;
           BatchCorrespondence CNR = new BatchCorrespondence();      
           ID idBatch = Database.executeBatch(CNR,Process); 
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
static testMethod void testMethod2(){        

    Settings__c PS = new ProcessSetting__c(name = 'Corr',Max_Process__c = 10);
    insert ps;
    system.debug('Process' + ps.Max_Process__c);
    CorreSchedule obj1 = new CorreSchedule ();
    String sch = '0 0 10 * * ?';
    test.startTest();    
    system.schedule('TestCheck', sch, obj1); 
    test.stopTest(); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your test class will not compile. Please find corrected code as per my understanding :

```
static testMethod void testMethod2(){        
         test.startTest();    
         Settings__c PS = new Setting__c(name = 'Corr',Process__c=10);
         insert ps;
         system.debug('Process' + ps.Process__c);
        BatchSchedule obj1 = new BatchSchedule();
         String sch = '0 0 10 * * ?';
         system.schedule('TestCheck', sch, obj1); 
         test.stopTest(); 
}
```

Also , error is seen on line 4 since , you are inserting custom setting with value as "Corre" in test class but in schedular you are fetching with name as "Corr".
Please find above corrected method.